# Want vinegar taste!

Tags: fermentation

I want to try fermenting sauerkraut but I love the vinegary taste. Can I add vinegar to the mix or is there another way to get a more vinegar taste?

Answer (score 3):

Pickling by fermentation is accomplished by bacteria that produce lactic acid.  The kraut will become more acidic and flavorful over time. Tasting the kraut, as it ferments, will help you learn where you like it the best.   This is different from vinegar pickles, where a vinegar based brine is used to flavor the product.  While not traditional, I see no reason why you couldn't add vinegar to your kraut.  I think you would want to do that once the fermentation is completed to your satisfaction.  Maybe even "dressing" portions that you will be eating.